# What is the "Private information" section of profile for?

Tags: support, profile-page

So the birthday field is used to display age in full years, ok, but what is the reason to fill out **Real name** and **Email** fields if they're not shown publicly? I know my name, so what's it for?

> [image]

Comment: I can only speculate but maybe it is used when the team needs to verify your identity for example if you claim you've lost access to your account?

Comment: Sounds like and important security feature. If that is true, then it should be made explicit.

Comment: If a moderator needs to contact you they can send you an email.

Comment: But I log in with my email, so they should have it already.

Comment: @user1306322 there are other options than e-mail/password (e.g. Google) to log in.

Comment: The birthday used to serve in order to show age. This was nullified after the profile page redesign, which removed the age so birthday is now the same as real name, which is explained in the dupe.